# How do I pass a function as parameter?

Tags: c++

What is the fastest and shortest way to pass a function as parameter of another function without using other libraries other than the std one in just one line?

I mean let's say we have a function `forloop(int x, *) {...}` that run a for loop from `0` to `x` running the `*` function; the function call should be something like: `forloop(3, **() { std::cout "Hi!"; });`.

PS: `*` and `**` are just placeholders for the function-by-argument type and the way to pass the function as argument.

Comment: You should probably use [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 provides anonymous functions:

```
forloop(3, []{ std::cout "Hi!"; });
```

**Example**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

 void forloop(int times, std::function<void()> f) {
     for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
         f();
     }
 }

int main() {
    forloop(3, [] () { std::cout << "Hello world"; });
}
```

Comment: What would the type of `*` be?

Comment: @Jeffrey The type is `std::function<void()>` - include <functional>

Comment: @phant0m: No, it will be **convertible** to `std::function<void()>`. Its exact type is unspecified but can be obtained by `decltype`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I did when testing, I only included it because he asked about being able to pass it.

Comment: I'm seriously confused right now. I've tried your way (std::function) but with no success. Can you please make an example of the prototype for `forloop` if I'm going to use it like your first example?

Comment: @Jeffrey: std::function and lambdas is part of C++11 . Does your compiler support C++11? If not, you could try boost::function and boost::lambda

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan, I have gcc 4.2.1. How do I check what version of C++ is it supporting?

Comment: @Jeffrey [**You need GCC 4.3 or later**](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try "pointers to member functions" if your function is a member of any class.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at several options.

1. function pointers, the C style way
2. `std::function` which is part of C++ TR1 and C++11
3. use functors and `std::ptr_fun` to adapt your function

The syntax you are showing is only going to work with C++11. Earlier C++ versions don't offer the possibility to define an anonymous function.

Comment: I'm not using any syntax, I just invented it. What would `*` and `**` replaced with (if I have C++11)?